# Hахождение количества четных и нечетных чисел в массиве

Tags: java

Всем привет. Учусь писать на Java. Пишу код, где создается массив из 10 чисел. Необходимо нахождения четных и нечетных чисел в массиве. Где здесь ошибка?

```
package javaguru;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;
    public class hw {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            int a = 0;
            int b = 0;

            int[] cats = new int[10];

            for (int i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {
                cats[i] = ((int) (Math.random()*100));
                System.out.println(cats[i]);
            }

            if (cats[a]%2 == 0) {
                a = a + 1;
            }else if (cats[a]%2 != 0) {
                    b = b + 1;
                }

                System.out.println("Сумма чисел = " + a);
                System.out.println("Сумма чисел = " + b);
              =
            }
    }
```

Выдаёт 0 и 1

Comment: Потому что вы условие проверяете только один раз, а нужен цикл, чтобы проверить все элементы.

Answer (score 2):

```java
package javaguru;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class hw {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
   int[] cats = new int[10];
   int countEven = 0;
   int countOdd = 0;

   for (int i = 0; i < cats.length; i++) {

      cats[i] = ((int) (Math.random()*100));
      System.out.print(cats[i] + " ");

      if ( cats[i] % 2 != 0 ){
         countOdd++;
      } else {
         countEven++;
      }
   }

   System.out.println();
   System.out.println("Odd count " + countOdd);
   System.out.println( "Even count " + countEven );
 }
}
```

Comment: По условию ведь нужно количество найти, а не сумму чисел

Comment: @gil9red, Ой, извиняюсь, увидел в выводе слово "Сумма" и что-то задумался. Код исправлен :)

Comment: Спасибо, работает, проанализирую)

Comment: Если ответ решает вашу проблему, вы можете его принять.